# ASP.NET razor incorrectly works multiselect dropdownlist

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

There is a drop-down list with a multiselect

```
<select asp-for="UsersListForAssignTo" id="selectUser" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.UsersList" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

I prepare a list, so that some values were selected by default

```
List<string> allUsers = await db.Users.Select(u => u.UserName).ToListAsync();
                List<string> usersAssignedTo = await db.MasterAssigmentTables.Where(mat => mat.TableId == id && mat.TableName == typeof(TestCaseDesign).Name).Include(mat => mat.User).Select(u => u.User.UserName).ToListAsync();
                List<SelectListItem> userListAssigned = new List<SelectListItem>();
                foreach (string user in allUsers)
                {
                    if (usersAssignedTo.Contains(user))
                    {
                        userListAssigned.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = user, Selected = true });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        userListAssigned.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = user, Selected = false });
                    }
                }
                ViewBag.UsersList = userListAssigned;
```

The value is passed to the model

```
 public List<string> UsersListForAssignTo { get; set; }
```

The problem is that when I use "asp-for" all values become unselected

If I remove the binding to the model - then everything is ok

How to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Selected` value of a `SelectListItem` is meaningless in this context. The only thing that matters is what's in `ModelState`. That object is composed of values from the request, anything in `ViewData` (including `ViewBag`), and finally values on the model passed into the view.

Long and short, if you want some options initially selected, they need to be present in the list you are binding to. Set `UsersListForAssignTo` to the list of values you want initially selected before returning the view, and you'll be fine.

Comment: It's sad, in the controller I'm only interested in the selected values. This will load the model with an unnecessary class.

Comment: Not really, and definitely not unnecessary. Just new up the model and set the property. Not that complicated.

Comment: If I understood you correctly.
I added to the model - public List<SelectListItem> UsersListForAssignTo { get; set; } . In the method get  controller, I initialized:  testCaseDesignECVM.UsersListForAssignTo = userListAssigned;
                    return PartialView("Details", testCaseDesignECVM);   If I do not specify asp-items - the system does not build a list from the model. If I build a list using asp-items - The problem remains - the data of the selected items are lost

Comment: So far I see only one solution. And it's ugly. Create two drop-down lists
: One hidden and attached to the model, The second is unattached to the model but is visible and with choice. on the submit in the script just pass the values to the hidden one)

Comment: No. Keep the List<int> you had and set that to a list of the ints that are supposed to be selected.

Comment: Something I do not understand where to put the list of int? At 'asp-for', I specify the list of selected values that I want to get in the controller (this is a list of string).In 'asp-items', I specify all possible values for the drop-down list( here the standard item(SelectListItem) does not work - does not mark selected.

Comment: Your `List<int>` is what you're binding to, so that goes in `asp-for`. Your `List<SelectListItem>` has your select options, so that goes in `asp-items`. You *already* had everything right, you simply needed to set your `List<int>` to the list of ids that should be selected.

Comment: And how do I get a list with the selected names?

Comment: You can query the database for the entities that match those selected IDs and then select the name, or you could even literally just have the list be the names. There's no rule that the option value has to be an id. It just has to be something uniquely identifiable. If the names are unique, you could simply compose your select with those and bind to a list of strings instead of ints.

Comment: It is very confusing( Option with hidden select looks simpler.

Comment: Id should coincide with value in SelectListItem?